# Can I remove the passcode on a ssl key after generating and submitting the csr?

Tags: ssl, key, crt, csr

I'd like to remove the SSL passcode on a generated SSL key but I've already generated the CSR from the pass-coded key. If I remove the passcode do I need to regenerate the CSR again or will the crt work fine with the un-pass-coded key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passcode is not a property of the certificate, but a property of the container format. So you can safely convert the private key to other format or remove the passcode .

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation. SSL is one of those pains that I only feel every couple years and never work with enough to grasp fully.